# Как удалить ',' в двухмерном массиве, используя list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
text=[['Hello, My name is John!'],
      ['And, Im from Canada'],
      ['I like play football,basketball']
     ]

text=[text[j] for i in range(len(text))
              for j in range(len(text[i])) if text[i][j] != ',']
print(text)
# Думала сделать через (if text[i][j] != ',') но оно 3 раза выводит 'Hello, My name is John!'
```

Answer (score 1):

А в лоб не устроит?

```
text=[['Hello, My name is John!'],
      ['And, Im from Canada'],
      ['I like play football,basketball']
     ]

for i in range(len(text)):
    for j in range(len(text[i])):
        text[i][j] = text[i][j].replace(',', '')

print(text)
```

или если все свернуть в одну строку:

```
text=[['Hello, My name is John!'],
      ['And, Im from Canada'],
      ['I like play football,basketball']
     ]

text = [[obj.replace(',', '') for obj in arr] for arr in text]

print(text)
```

Comment: О Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется ввиду *убрать запятые внутри вложенных списков*, то вот:

```py
text=[['Hello, My name is John!'],
      ['And, Im from Canada'],
      ['I like play football,basketball']]

text = [[''.join([i for i in j if i != ','])] for j in t]

print(text)

# [['Hello My name is John!'], ['And Im from Canada'], ['I like play footballbasketball']]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!